# Calculate the pressure in a container given moles and volume

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

Say there are two containers with the same volume. The first has a temperature T and pressure P and contains 1 mole of $O_2$. The second has a temperature 2T and contains 1 mole of $He_2$. I'd like to calculate the value of the pressure of the second container.

I can use the conservation of energy to solve this problem.

$$U_1 = U_2$$

$$\frac 5 2 nRT = \frac 3 2nR2T$$

$$0.205 T = 0.246 T$$

$$T = 0$$

$$2P_1 = P_2$$

Maybe I'm on the wrong track using those equations and I apologize for my blatant ignorance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's an error between lines 2 and 3. You can simplify your last equation by $T$ and $V$ since $V_1$ and $V_2$ are the same.

Comment: You need to use total internal energy before mixing = total internal energy after mixing.  $U_{O_2,i} + U_{He,i} = U_{O_2,f} + U_{He,f}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$PV=1\times RT \space For \space O_2 $$
$$ P_2V=1\times R\times 2\times  T \space for\space He2$$
Divide Both
$\frac{PV}{P_2V}=\frac{T}{2T}$
$$\frac{P}{P_2}=1/2$$

Comment: So there's no way to tell the absolute value of $P_2$?

Comment: @Cesare Yes, if we know P we can find P2

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way we can calculate P?

Comment: From the Relation PV=RT if we measure Temp and Volume of Cylinder and Knowing value of Gas Constant(R=8.314) we can calculate

Comment: Thank you. One last question: is that how you would approach the exercise in my question?

Comment: Yes.  This is strictly an ideal gas law problem.